# R - copy partialed column into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
ID year value
1 1980 1.5
2 1980 1.6
3 1982 1.4
4 1982 1.9
5 1984 2.0
6 1984 1.2
```

I want to turn this into the following:

```
ID year value.1980 value.1982 value.1984
1 1980 1.5 NA NA
2 1980 1.6 NA NA
3 1982 NA 1.4 NA
4 1982 NA 1.9 NA
5 1984 NA NA 2.0
6 1984 NA NA 1.2
```

So I want to split the "value" column into as many columns as I have values in the column "years", and I want those columns to only show values for their respective year. Is there an efficient way to achieve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a copy of year column and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(year1 = year) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year1, values_from = value, names_prefix = 'value.')

#    ID  year value.1980 value.1982 value.1984
#  <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1  1980        1.5       NA         NA  
#2     2  1980        1.6       NA         NA  
#3     3  1982       NA          1.4       NA  
#4     4  1982       NA          1.9       NA  
#5     5  1984       NA         NA          2  
#6     6  1984       NA         NA          1.2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1982L, 1982L, 
1984L, 1984L), value = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.9, 2, 1.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(year1 = year) %>% 
    spread(year1, value) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(matches('^\\d+')), ~ str_c('value.', .))
```

-output

```
#  ID year value.1980 value.1982 value.1984
#1  1 1980        1.5         NA         NA
#2  2 1980        1.6         NA         NA
#3  3 1982         NA        1.4         NA
#4  4 1982         NA        1.9         NA
#5  5 1984         NA         NA        2.0
#6  6 1984         NA         NA        1.2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1982L, 1982L, 
1984L, 1984L), value = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.9, 2, 1.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach using `dcast` in order to reshape the `df` dataset from `long` to `wide`. `paste0` from `base r` is used to concatenate the variable name with `value.`.

```r
library(data.table)

# Data:

df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1982L, 1982L, 
1984L, 1984L), value = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.9, 2, 1.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Code:

setDT(df)
df[, year_1 := year]
dcast(df, ... ~ paste0("value.", year_1), fun.aggregate = sum)

#Output:

#>    ID year value.1980 value.1982 value.1984
#> 1:  1 1980        1.5        0.0        0.0
#> 2:  2 1980        1.6        0.0        0.0
#> 3:  3 1982        0.0        1.4        0.0
#> 4:  4 1982        0.0        1.9        0.0
#> 5:  5 1984        0.0        0.0        2.0
#> 6:  6 1984        0.0        0.0        1.2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>